# How are you supposed to access EJB when using Easyrest?

Tags: java, jboss, resteasy

I have been trying to get Resteasy to work (and not it dose). However I now have another headache with accessing the EJB:s. I have tried injecting them, looking them up with jndi and most other solutions but none of them works.

I get massages like: java.lang.RuntimeException: Class is not a root resource.

Or: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong target.

Or just: NullPointer

Using JBoss 5.1.0.GA and Resteasy 1.2.1.GA... Can't find any documentation on how this could be done. Do anybody know?

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this: [EJB Integration](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.2.GA/userguide/html_single/index.html#RESTEasy_EJB_Integration)?

> Resteasy currently only has simple integration with EJBs. To make an EJB a JAX-RS resource, you must annotate an SLSB's @Remote or @Local interface with JAX-RS annotations:
>
> Next, in RESTeasy's web.xml file you must manually register the EJB with RESTeasy using the resteasy.jndi.resources

Comment: Yes, this much I have understood but it dosen't help me. I do not want to make my EJB:s restful. I would like to access my EJB:s from a restful pojo/servlet. Mixing the ejb-layer with the web-layer (which I would say that rest is) would be bad design.

So I refrase my question, is it possible to access the ejb:s from a restful bean in the web-layer?

Comment: Anyway it should be possible to get the EJB through JNDI like this:
    InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
    ejbLocal = (EJBeanLocal) ctx.lookup("deployed-ear/EJBean/local");

However this gives me: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong target.

Comment: I have the same issue: in my case the 'wrong target' problem stands only when the EJB accepts pojos, not when the parameters are native Java classes such as strings. @Peter: did you solve the problem somehow?